# ReactJS: Navbar Current Page Effect

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want the highlight effect when I'm on the current page. For example, if I'm on the About Page, I woudl like About to be highlighted in the navbar.

How would I do that?

#### Relevant Code

**NavBar.js**

```
function NavBar() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    NavBar.handleClickOutside = () => setOpen(false);

    return(
        <nav>
            <div className='navbar-container'>
                <a href='/' className='logo'>Daniel Zhang</a>
                <div className='toggle-button' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                    <div className='bar' />
                    <div className='bar' />
                    <div className='bar' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='nav-links' className={open ? 'nav-open' : 'nav-collasped'}>
                <a href='/'>Home</a>
                <a href='/about'>About</a>
                {/* <a href='/blog'>Blog</a> */}
                <a href='/contact'>Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

const clickOutsideConfig = {
    handleClickOutside: () => NavBar.handleClickOutside,
};

export default onClickOutside(NavBar, clickOutsideConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the NavLink component from react router dom. Import like:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And instead of   `<a href='/about'>About</a>`   you can write:

```
<NavLink exact to='/about'  activeClassName="highlighted">About</Navlink>
```

And so on for the other links present within the `<div id='nav-links'`.
Of course you can add the highlighted styles based on the `.highlighted`

More info, see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink